# On var and hoisting in javascript, and blocks not being scopes

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, hoisting

I know that I should use `let` and `const`, but I still want to understand this.
Look at this code:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

I understand that `var`s are hoisted, and that that is happening in this case because blocks are not scopes. This in mind, I can guess that javascript is reading that code as follows:

```
var i;
...
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    ...
}
...
```

But I don't see how that should be a problem. The way this is translating in my mind is as such:

```
{// i = 0;
funcs[0] = function() {
    console.log(0);
};
}
...
```

The only way in which I think that this makes sense is if javascript is storing `i` by reference, and not value. Could someone please elaborate on this?

**Answer:**

> `console.log(i=0)` is never true, it is evaluated as: `funcs[i=0] = function() { console.log(i) }`. the function has been declared, but has not been called, and that i has not been evaluated.
>
> from user120242.

> "this makes sense is if javascript is storing i by reference, and not
> value." - yes, closures in javascript do capture variables by
> reference, they do not capture the current value of a variable when
> the closure is created.
>
> from Bergi.

Comment: because i is 3 when the loop finishes, thus code inside the for loop will be using 3, not the current value of i for that iteration of the loop, which is what most people expect.  console.log(0) is not correct.  it is console.log(i), and `i` is evaluated when the function is called

Comment: "it is console.log(i)" huh? why doesn't `i` get evaluated inside the function also? @user120242

Comment: the function assigned to funcs[i] is not executed until it is called.  `i` is not evaluated for its value until the function is called, by which time `i`'s value has been incremented to 3.  `console.log(i=0)` is never true, it is evaluated as: funcs[i=0] = function() { console.log(i) }.  the function has been declared, but has not been called, and that i has not been evaluated.

Comment: "*this makes sense is if javascript is storing `i` by reference, and not value.*" - yes, closures in javascript do capture variables by reference, they do not capture the current value of a variable when the closure is created.